# AMPL double conditions in constraints

Tags: optimization, conditional-statements, mathematical-optimization, cplex, ampl

I'm working on an optimization project and I'm using AMPL with CPLEX for this.
My problem is somehow simple but I couldn't do it without using some additional "useless" variables.

So assume I have the following code:

```
set A:= a b c;
set B:= 1 2 3;
var x{A,B} binary;
```

now I want a constraint to be processed under 2 conditions, for example:

```
if x[a,1] = 1 and x[a,2] = 1 then (some constraint).
```

Unfortunately, CPLEX won't let me use the syntax:

```
s.t const: x[a,1] = 1 and x[a,2] = 1 ==> (some constraint)
```

it says "logical constraint _slogcon[1] is not an indicator constraint.

Now the way I did it was by introducing a new variable.

```
var dummyVar{A,A,B,B} binary;
```

this variable is equal to 1 if both x[a,1] = 1 and x[a,2] = 1.

```
subject to condition: 2*dummyVar[a,a,1,2] <= x[a,1] + x[a,2]
```

My problem is with the large model I'm working with. In my case, this dummyVar is not simply a small set, it contains a set of sets. When AMPL is processing the code (translating it to be read by CPLEX), it crashes due to lack of memory.

Is there any simple way to write something like

```
s.t const: x[a,1] = 1 and x[a,2] = 1 ==> (some constraint)
```

without introducing any additional variables? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To model this effectively, you should consider two things

1. 'some-constraint' is linear or quadratic.
2. if either x[a,1] or x[a,2] are 1, then the constraint can be violated.

On point 1, your some-constraint is of the form

```
l <= f(x) <= u
```

where f(x) is a quadratic of linear function and l and u are constraints.  If you let f_max and f_min be the upper and lower bounds of the function f(x) over all feasible values of `x`  then you can write your conditional constraint as

```
l - (l - f_min) (x[a,1] + x[a,2]) <= f(x) <= u + (f_max - u)(x[a,1] + x[a,2])
```

If either x[a,1] or x[a,2] are 1 then the constraint becomes

```
f_min <= f(x) <= f_max
```

or looser if both x[a,1] and x[a,2] are both 1.  If both are 0, then the original constraint is enforced.

Comment: Thank you sir, in case the constraint I want to apply if x[a,b1] = 1 and x[a,b2] = 1 is that (  abs(b1-b2) >= 2  ) [in other words, I want x[a,b1] and x[a,b2] to be = 1 if and only if abs(b1-b2) >= 2], will this technique work? Also, how can I specify the "l" and "u" values? Thanks you again.